# iText open PDF with Username and Password secured by Vitrium

Tags: java, itext

I have a PDF which is secured with Vitrium (it says so) with a Username and a Password.
How can i open this file in iText?
Username and password are known for the PDF.
I tried a few things but I have no clue how to solve this.

Comment: PDFs can be _secured_ in two ways, through an "owner" password or through a "user" password. There are no provisions for a username. You can see what which means on this [demo lab](https://itextpdf.com/en/demos/protect-pdf-files-free-online). If you are using an Owner password, you can test that [here](https://itextpdf.com/en/demos/unlock-pdf-password-free-online). I will add the Answer below, if that is the case, for safe keeping.

Comment: Vitrium appears to offer propriety DRM. Their web site appears to be pure buzzword bingo, at least the page shown on my mobile phone was void of actual information. Thus, no technical details are available at fingertip. It's merely clear that it's non-standard. To support their proprietary protection, therefore, you'll have to contact them and integrate their service.